# RichTextBox and tab key

Tags: c#, forms

I created a richTextBox and i noticed that when I press Tab key it is not doing anything.
It is suppose to do some space but it do not.

How can i access it?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

By default pressing tab moves focus to the next control. Setting AcceptsTab property of the RichTextBox to `true` allows the RichTextBox to accept tab characters.

See this MSDN article on the [AcceptsTab property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textboxbase.acceptstab.aspx).

Comment: Ok thank you it is now working.
But i can see that the pointer moving too much.
Is there a way that I can control the number of space that it is do?

Answer (score 1):

First you need to set following properties of Richtextbox

```
richTextBox.Multiline = true;
richTextBox.AcceptsTab = true;
```

And in the keypress event of richtextbox you need to do following

```
if (e.KeyChar == 9)
{
    e.Handled = false;
}
```